# Сломанное меню из-за одного символа

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем привет! Вчера столкнулся с такой проблемой, что у меня сломалась вёрстка, долго не мог понять почему, копал-копал и наконец-то докопался до истины и смог это воспроизвести. У меня есть горизонтальное выпадающее меню. Но в некоторых случаях выпадающие подменю появляется справа от блока, на который наводишь, а не снизу.

Я буду очень благодарен, если кто-то сможет объяснить из-за чего такое вообще происходит. Ниже 2 примера с кодом: хороший вариант и плохой вариант.

Вёрстка чинится из-за того, что я добавил *символ переноса строки (или любой другой символ)* между элементом `a` и `ul`. Для меня это поведение очень непонятное и я хотел бы разобраться как можно избежать подобных ситуаций.

```css
.menu {
  text-align: center;
}

.menu ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.menu > ul > li {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0; 
}

.menu li ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.menu li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
Хороший вариант:

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Пункт 1-1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Пункт 2-1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

Плохой вариант:

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Пункт 1-1</a><!--
      --><ul>
        <li><a href="">Пункт 2-1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**UPDATE #1**

Проверил данный код в паре браузеров:

1. **Google Chrome 63.0.3239.84**: хороший вариант - подменю снизу, плохой вариант - подменю справа.
2. **Firefox 57.0.2**: оба варианта - подменю справа.
3. **Internet Explorer 11.726.15063.0**: оба варианта - подменю справа.

Answer (score 0):

Покопал еще глубже. Разобрался. Проблема была в том, что у элемента `.menu ul` выставлен `display: inline-block` (нужен для корректного центрирования, с помощью `text-align: center`).
Исправил данную проблему тем, что изменил способ центрирования.

Следующий пример работает во всех приведённых в вопросе браузерах для обоих вариантов.

```css
.menu {
  float: left;
  left: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.menu > ul {
  float: left;
  right: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.menu > ul > li {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li ul {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0; 
}

.menu li ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.menu li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 1-1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 2-1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```